# Embed salesforce web to lead form on WordPress without page refresh

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I want to embed a form on my wordpress website that creates a lead in salesforce.
I tried embedding the form directly, however it reloads the entire website when a lead information(email address) is submitted.

Also, I tried using WordPress-to-lead plugin which provided same result.

Is there a way to submit the information without having the entire page to refresh.

Any help on this would be appreciated

thanks